# Are these valid transformations, Please guide

Tags: passive-networks, electrical

[image: Circuit]

Please help check if the transformations in the pink are allowed, when solving a circuit. For the given circuit the goal is to find the current I1 which could be found using nodal without taking care of the particular position of the resistor . However,I am curious why or why not the given transformation will effect the any parameter of a circuit. Please do let me know if any more clarification is required.

Comment: Those three branches are equivalent. Transformations are "as seen from outside." So long as you don't need to figure out something inside of the "box", then the transformation doesn't affect circuit parameters (those outside the box.) But if you need to find out something that's going on inside of the box -- for example, if here you wanted to know the voltage drop across the \$3\:\Omega\$ resistor, then the transformations may help you get there but they loose sight also of that interior detail. You can use what you learn, though, and get there.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes** those transformations are allowed **since they are in series**.

---

And here's why mathematically, we can see to the left that it's 21 V across the rightmost branch.

This gives you the following KVL equation:

\$21 = 3I+60+10I\$

And that is the exact same thing as

\$
21 = 60+13I\\
21 = 13I+60
\$